# hibernate optional relationship not showing data

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am using hibernate with MySQL Db. I have a table of business with some fields and relations. in relations, one relation is optional.

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
 @JoinColumn(name = "modified_by", nullable = true)
 public Users getModifiedBy() {
     return this.modifiedBy;
 }

public void setModifiedBy(Users modifiedBy) {
    this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
}
```

now when I fetch data using the following hql it work fine

```
   String hql = "from Business";
   Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
   list = query.list();
```

if i changed hql to the following then it shows 0 result.

```
String hql = "select new com.ba.Business(business.businessId,business.slUsersByCreatedBy.userId,business.modifiedBy.userId,business.bizType.bizTypeId) from  com.ba.Business business order by business.businessName";
```

How to manage this as modifiedBy is null. There were different solution available which i tried like setting optional to true and setting @NotFound but nothing worked.
SQL Created by hql is following.

```
select  business0_.business_id as col_0_0_,  business0_.createdBy as col_1_0_,  business0_.modified_by as col_5_0_,  business0_.biz_type_id as col_9_0_ from  _business  business0_, _users  users1_, _users  users4_,  _biz_type  biztype7_  where  business0_.createdBy= users1_.web_user_id and  business0_.modified_by= users4_.web_user_id and  business0_.biz_type_id= biztype7_.biz_type_id  order by  business0_.business_name
```

it is using "and" for joins. If i explicitly add joins by adding following with hql then the result remain same.

```
left join business.modifiedBy  modifiedBy
```

Is there any solution available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `business.modifiedBy` in the query, it implicitly converts to `inner join`, and that's why you don't get any results. Change it to this and it should work

```
String hql = "select new com.ba.Business(business.businessId, business.slUsersByCreatedBy.userId, mb.userId, business.bizType.bizTypeId) from  com.ba.Business business left join business.modifiedBy mb order by business.businessName";
```

Comment: if you notice my last line i have shown you that i have applied left join but it didnt work.

Comment: Yes but you then have to reference it in the `select` part with `modifiedBy`, and not `business.modifiedBy`.